# How to test redux action by onClick with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following function I am trying to test with enzyme.

```
renderLoginLink(caption) {
return (
  <a href="#" id="lnkAuthenticateWithGoogle" onClick={() => this.props.actions.authenticateWithGoogle()}>
    {caption}
  </a>
);
}
```

I'm using this to simulate the click.

```
let container, store
const mockStore = configureMockStore();
store = mockStore(initialState);
container = mount(<Provider store={store}><Login {...initialState} /></Provider>)
container.find("a#lnkAuthenticateWithGoogle").simulate("click")
```

I am getting an error that **this.props.actions** is undefined. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While mounting the component, you would need to provide the actions as props to it like

```
let container, store
const mockStore = configureMockStore();
store = mockStore(initialState);
const actions = {
     authenticateWithGoogle: jest.fn()
}
container = mount(<Provider store={store}><Login {...initialState} actions={actions}/></Provider>)
container.find("a#lnkAuthenticateWithGoogle").simulate("click")
```

Comment: Do you know how to tell if the action was called via expect?